# How can I see how long I have played a game on Xbox for one day?

Tags: xbox-one

I have been wanting to know how long I have been playing ROBLOX, but only during a single day.

Comment: Would you mind providing more detail? It's rather hard to know exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Just time yourself. Idk that Xbox has an internal clock to keep track of that kind of stuff